# PHP not evaluating expression from left to right?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following expression:

```
if (!empty($forums) && count($forums) == 1)
```

Based on the order of evaluation, the first thing it should check is if `$forums` is not empty. If it is empty, then it should evaluate to false immediately when it hits the `&&`. At that point it should exit out of the if statement and not even attempt the `count()`.

However, this error was produced:

> ErrorException: [E_WARNING] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

The stack trace shows that it attempted to do `count(NULL)`. If `$forums` is evaluating to `NULL`; then why is the expression continuing instead of exiting out of the if statement?

Comment: What is `$forums` anyway?

Comment: Is `$forums` definitely evaluating to `null`?

Comment: You only can count arrays (or countables / iteratables). Read the error description.

Comment: `$forums` is always either an array or NULL.

Comment: Is the actual value `NULL` being checked or is `NULL` a string? Try logging the result of `gettype($forums)`.

Comment: Can you dump is_array($forums); see if it's really an array?

Comment: Please share the rest of the code.

Comment: FFS people: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Answer (score 1):

Check if your variable is really something that PHP can count. Judging by you only test for if it is empty, it even could be an object or something different that PHP just can't count. Rather than testing for `empty()` I would suggest you:

```
if (is_array($forums) && count($forums) == 1) {
    // do stuff.
}
```

If it is an array it can't be empty so you do not even need to check that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if $forms is an array. You should use is_array to check if its an array.

https://codebrace.com/editor/b03bb92ab

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//codebrace.com/embed/b03bb92ab/?12px&amp;wordwrap&amp;php&amp;result&amp;xcode&amp;focus=php" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="background-color:transparent; overflow: hidden;margin: 0;" title="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```